# I ran into some problems with Recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion, return

The task is to implement a program which counts how many different Sums of Primes there are for a given number `sumtoBreak`.

The Method `primeSum` should subtract all possible primes `currprime` from the number `sumtoBreak` until the `sumtoBreak` becomes zero and then return (in sum) a one for each possibilty. To account for all possibilities, in each recession step, it calls itself

1. with `sumtoBreak - currprime` plus
2. calls itself with the `nextPrime`.

My Problem is that java won't return anything unless the `sumtoBreak` is zero right at the beginning.
Would be glad for any advice!

Here's the code (I know that the parenthesis in the code with the nested if statements are redundant, but I just wanted to make sure, that's not the problem):

Here's the fixed code:

```
public class PrimeSum {
    public static boolean isPrime(int primecandidate) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i <= primecandidate / 2; i++) {
            if (primecandidate % i == 0)
                count++;
        }
        if (count == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static int nextPrime(int currprime) {
        int j = currprime + 1;
        while (!isPrime(j))
            j++;
        return j;
    }

    public static int primeSum(int sumtoBreak, int currprime) {
        if (sumtoBreak == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            if (sumtoBreak < 0 || currprime > sumtoBreak) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return primeSum(sumtoBreak, nextPrime(currprime)) + primeSum(sumtoBreak - currprime, currprime);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(primeSum(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: What arguent are you passing to the program? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Please, indent your code properly. The IDE can do that for you, with just a keyboard shortcut. Doing that will probably make you realize, for example, that your for loop is guaranteed to only ever execute one iteration, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: And while you are fixing the formatting of the program, also note that there are coding conventions. Do not use variable names or method names that start with a capital letter (like `NextPrime` or `N`). Only class, interface and enum names are supposed to start with a capital. Also, give your variables meaningful names, like `currPrime` instead of `p`, `primeCandidate` instead of `k`, and `sumToBreak` instead of `N`. One letter variables should only be used in loops.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your advice. I fixed the for loop, but it didn't resolve my problem. I enter any sumtoBreak and the program returns 0 unless the sumtoBreak is 0. I assumed that it should add a one for every path the sumtoBreak eventually becomes zero, and if the path is not a sum it should return zero and add all paths together (one if the path correspond to a sum of primes and zero if not). Here's the new code:

Comment: If you fixed what we asked for, please [edit] the question, replace the code and don't forget to use the `{}` button to format it. Also, add the information about what you input, what you expect and what happens **to the question**.

Comment: well, the code is too long... Even if run the code with 2 as argument it return zero. I assumed it should subtract the two in one path - the the sumtoBreak becomes 0 - and return 1.

Comment: Note that your for loop in `isPrime` will only loop for one iteration, due to the break statement.

Comment: sorry, I didn't know how to edit. I finally got it..

Comment: I tried to enter the code here in the comment line

Comment: You should replace the `currprime>=sumtoBreak` with `currprime>sumtoBreak`. BTW, you still didn't indent it properly. Let your IDE format your code.

Comment: thanks, it works now! (even though I do not understand why). As I wrote I am new to programming and use an IDE the first time for this program. Is the code now properly indented ?  (BTW sorry for my poor English).

Comment: @maxfried your English needs no apology; I've seen much worse from supposed native speakers...

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question, but corrects an error in your isPrime Method and computes the result ***much*** faster:

```
private static boolean isPrime(final int primecandidate) {

    if ( primecandidate <  2) {        // 0 & 1 are NOT Prime
        return false;
    }
    if ((primecandidate & 0x1) == 0) { // Even is NOT Prime...
        return primecandidate  == 2;   // ...except for 2 (and 0).
    }
    for (int i = 2, iMax = (int) Math.sqrt(primecandidate); i <= iMax; i++) {
        if (primecandidate % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note the following:

- the final argument primecandidate is marked final
- it corrects the result for 0 & 1 to false
- the method is marked private
- the iMax is Sqrt(primecandidate) & not primecandidate / 2
- iMax is calculated once, instead of every iteration
- I use a strategy I call "if you're done, be done."
  Meaning: don't set a flag (in your case count), just get out!

Please note also, there is an apache commons Math3 function...

> org.apache.commons.math3.primes.Primes.isPrime(j)

It is *significantly* slower for smallish values (<= Short.MAX_VALUE)
It is *somewhat* faster for largeish values (ca. Integer.MAX_VALUE)

There is also a BigInteger.isProbablePrime(...) function, but my Benchmark suggests it is rather slow.

I hope this helps a little?

Answer (score 0):

*Some things you might have missed:*

in a function, a `return` statement terminates (`break`) the function immediatly. So in

```
if(...) { return ...; }
else {...}
```

→ `else` is redundant, as if the condition is true, the function is already terminated (`break`)

Something like `a==0` has a `boolean` value (`true` or `false`). So

> if(count==0) { return false; }
>
> else { return true;}

can be shortened to `return count!=0;`

I recommend to always use braces, because something like `if(i==0) ++i; break;`, means `if(i==0) {++i;}`. `break;` will be called in any case.

```
public static boolean
isPrime(int n)
{
  if(n==0 || n==1) { return false; }

  for(int i= 2; i <= n/2; ++i)
  {
    if(n%i == 0) { return false; } //we know, n is not a prime,
                                   //so function can break here
  }
  return true; //since for all values of i, the function did not break,
               //n is a prime
}
```

I wish you a lot of motivation to code for the future!

Comment: The above calculates the result incorrectly for EVERY value except 0 & 1. I've posted an edit to correct that, but until its been published, this comment.

Comment: thanks for pointing out false and true must be switched. I corrected the bug.